# Common shared views. Views + ViewModels or UserControls?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, shared-libraries, viewmodel

I am developing a little utility view that will be embedded in several of our apps. It will sit in a common library.

Should I expose this as a ViewModel along with a default View implementation, or would it be better as a UserControl with a fixed GUI?

It is pretty self contained and I doubt it will need to be reskinned, but doing it as a UserControl seems a bit overkill with having to set up a load of dependency properties.

A simple ViewModel seems more attractive to me but wondered if this was the normal way of sharing stuff?

**EDIT:** 
It would also be nice if I could embed this in WinForms apps too. Is this possible with View/ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I went with View/ViewModel. This keeps the separation nicely and is easily pluggable into existing MVVM projects.

It also works fine in WinForms, given that a View is just a `UserControl` with its `DataContext` set to some arbitrary object (the ViewModel).

The only slight issue I had was the fact that `Application.Current` is not set in a forms environment, so I had to store the GUI dispatcher reference so I could marshal gui updates to the proper thread in my ViewModel.